# From the given array of numbers find all the of numbers in group of 3 with sum value N

Tags: algorithm

Given is a array of numbers:

```
1, 2, 8, 6, 9, 0, 4
```

We need to find all the numbers in group of three which sums to a value N ( say 11 in this example). Here, the possible numbers in group of three are:

```
{1,2,8}, {1,4,6}, {0,2,9}
```

The first solution I could think was of O(n^3). Later I could improve a little(n^2 log n) with the approach:

```
1. Sort the array.
2. Select any two number and perform binary search for the third element.
```

Can it be improved further with some other approaches?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do it in `O(n^2)`: for each `i` in the array, test whether two other values sum to `N-i`.

You can test in `O(n)` whether two values in a sorted array sum to `k` by sweeping from both ends at once. If the sum of the two elements you're on is too big, decrement the "right-to-left" index to make it smaller. If the sum is too small, increment the "left-to-right" index to make it bigger. If there's a pair that works, you'll find them, and you perform at most `2*n` iterations before you run out of road at one end or the other. You might need code to ignore the value you're using as `i`, depends what the rules are.

You could instead use some kind of dynamic programming, working down from `N`, and you probably end up with time something like `O(n*N)` or so. Realistically I don't think that's any better: it looks like all your numbers are non-negative, so if `n` is much bigger than `N` then before you start you can quickly throw out any large values from the array, and also any duplicates beyond 3 copies of each value (or 2 copies, as long as you check whether `3*i == N` before discarding the 3rd copy of `i`). After that step, `n` is `O(N)`.